# How to set autoFocus on input field in Formik form?

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am trying to set auto focus on input fields in a Formik form using React. What is the standard way of doing this?

My code is below:

```
                                         <img src="images/barcode-small.png" alt="Barcode Small" />
                                       </td>
                                       <td>
                                         <Field name="barcode1"
                                                type="text"
                                                className="p-inputtext"
                                                autocomplete="off"
                                                style={{ width: 250 }}/>
                                       </td>
```

I've tried simply adding the autoFocus attribute to the Field but that didn't seem to work.
In my dev tools I am getting the following error:
[image: Browser dev error]

How do I check what is blocking the focus?
Thanks

Comment: Read the error. It says another element is already focused. That is why the auto-fosus for you is not working.

Comment: Yeah it must be built in Formik. Seems like its the form Submit button. Do you know how to bypass this?

Comment: You would have to show me the whole code of the file. Without it I can't help.

Comment: @StiaanWolfaardt: As per the comments and error, I reckon, you have added the autoFocus attribute to all Field elements and not just one. Please paste-in the full code so that the community can help you better without any guesses.

Answer (score 6):

you can simply use TextInput to do this, as i have done
Just add a property of

```
<TextInput autoFocus={true} />
```

and see the result

Comment: `TextInput` is React Native specific, which i don't see mentioned anywhere in the question. what about Formik [Field](https://formik.org/docs/api/field)?

Comment: It worked in my formik in ReactJS as well.

Comment: Saved 15 lines of code. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you can use useEffect combined with the document.getElementByName. Here is how;

run useEffect just once using empty bracets:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    document.getElementsByName("name of your formik element")[0].focus();

    // following is optional
    return () => {
      formik.resetForm();
    }
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

For those coming along in the future:

I was using a React class component in this question. I managed to solve the problem by adding a method that handles the focus. by getting an element by ID in the DOM.

```
focusChange(nextField) {
 if(document.getElementById(nextField) === null){
   return;
 }
 document.getElementById(nextField).focus();
```

}

And then in the render method of the class I checked for a key event. The keycode 13(enter) check was to prevent a submit of the form.

```
const onKeyDown = (keyEvent) => {
     if ((keyEvent.charCode || keyEvent.keyCode) === 13) {
       this.focusChange(this.state.nextBarcode);
       keyEvent.preventDefault();
       keyEvent.keyCode = 9;
     }
   }
```

I added the method to my Formik form:

```
<Form onKeyDown={onKeyDown}>
```

And the actual input field that comes from PrimeReact looks like:

```
<InputText
      className="p-inputtext"
      id='barcode4'
      onChange={(e) => this.setState({barcode4: e.target.value, nextBarcode: 'barcode5'})}
      value={this.state.barcode4}
      style={{ width: 250 }} />
```

So the solution for me was `document.getElementById("myID").focus();`

Answer (score 0):

To have a Formik Field component auto-focused, add the autoFocus prop to the Field component as shown below:

```
<Field 
autoFocus={true}
type="text"
name="barcode1"  
/>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).